# First time DM for semi-experienced group: which module?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, game-recommendation

My group's currently finishing *Princes of the Apocalypse* and I will be DM'ing the next campaign (D&D 5e). I've never done it before and I can't decide on the module. I don't mind prep and some improv at all, but I want to have something to fall back on, as a first timer. There are also some additional complications:

- We can't play *Curse of Strahd* or *Tomb of Annihilation* because one of the players has DM'ed and is playing them, respectively.
- We've already played *Lost Mine of Phandelver*.

My players have said I can pick the module, but I asked for some preferences and they said they would prefer a campaign with a story (not dungeon crawling), preferably linear with the option to mess around every once in a while. (The PotA sandbox got a little "why are we here again?" at the end.)

AFAIK this leaves *Out of the Abyss, Storm King's Thunder* and *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist*.

Our party would have:

- Fighter (as yet undecided on race)
- Dragonborn paladin
- Bard (as yet undecided on race)
- Goliath barbarian
- Aasimar sorcerer

Personally I’m not leaning towards Waterdeep bc it only goes up to L5. My research indicated STK has a solid beginning and end, but you basically DIY inbetween, and the OotA gets a little repetitive and there's a million NPC's to keep track of as DM.

What would more experienced DM’s recommend? One of these three or something else altogether?

Comment: Hi agirlnamedfia, and welcome. Unfortunately we've learned we don't handle requests very well, as you can see at the various links in the close-notice. That said, I strongly hope you'll pop into [chat] and ask the same question: I, personally, have played or run all the adventures you're talking about, and I know plenty of other chatizens have, too. You'll need 20 reputation to participate, so I've thrown you an upvote to get you 1/4 of the way there. Hope to see you soon!